# Android VideoView streaming issues

Tags: java, c#, android, video, video-streaming

In my android app, I am using HLS streaming from hls links provided by Vimeo, using very standard streaming code with VideoView.

```
    var uri = global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url);
    video.SetVideoURI(uri);
    video.Start();`
```

In my activity, media player's error listener is already implemented and bound to the videoview, yet it is not triggered.

However, on some videos, after a couple of minutes, video stops abruptly, buffering starts again and all of a sudden videoview's completion event is triggered even though the user is only a couple of minutes into the video.

Why would the completion event be triggered and is there an alternative or better way to stream videos? Could the issue be videos' encoding or vimeo servers etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not already using it then try using [ExoPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html).

and please share your logcat.